# Serving single JS and CSS file in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, minify, sprockets

Expanding on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html -- I have a lot of separate JS and CSS files for desktop, mobile, different plugins etc.

Is there a way to join them all into single JS and CSS files with Rails? I'm using Sprockets with UglifyJS for JS and YUI Compressor for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your link in [section 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production), `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` will take care of compiling your assets into single JS and CSS files on production. This should typically be part of your deployment script.

Are your custom assets not getting included in the pipeline for some reason?

Comment: Well, asset precompilation works great. It's just that the files aren't joined together. Say I have `application.js`, `application_desktop.js` and `application_mobile.js` -- these will remain separated (each with their own digest string added to the filename ofcourse).